# How to convert OBJ/FBX to GLTF before loading to scene (using Threejs)

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d, fbx, gltf

I am trying to create to create a webapp in which users can upload obj/fbx files and view them in the browser. I have used the OBJLoader and FBXLoader which Threejs provides and it is all working fine. I however want to ***convert both these models to GTLF before loading them*** into the scene (for the sake of consistency).

How can I achieve this in threejs? I know that threejs has a GTLF exporter but I am unaware of how to leverage it for my purposes.

Comment: There is no such functionality in three.js. Only if you write your own converter, but it's hell of work. Why do you want to do it, if everything works fine with FBX and OBJ loaders?

Comment: Thanks for the response. Well the ultimate aim is to get all formats of models to a uniform gltf format which can be then converted easily to sfb/usdz formats for android and ios phones. Trying to reduce the number of converters I have to write overall.

Comment: Are you trying to let the user download the glTF file after this? Or just to display it? If only for display, I don't think there's any benefit to loading, exporting, and re-loading.

Comment: @DonMcCurdy Just trying to display it. Will having a uniform format (gltf in this case) to work with not be useful? Which format is most parsable?

Comment: The problem is that you'd be converting A->B->C->B here, where "B" is a three.js object. If anything is wrong with B the first time, converting it to glTF and back isn't going to fix that. I'd argue that glTF is most reliable starting point, if you have the choice, though.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you could do this:

Method 1:

- Convert using from OBJ or FBX to glTF using native libraries on your server, like obj2gltf and fbx2gltf.
- Load the glTF file on the web app.

Method 2:

- Load the OBJ or FBX using OBJLoader or FBXLoader, giving you a THREE.Mesh or other object.
- Convert that THREE.Mesh to a glTF file using GLTFExporter.
- Load the glTF file using GLTFLoader, giving you a THREE.Mesh or other object again.

Method 1 is harder, but may give you better conversion results because the native libraries have access to the FBX SDK. Method 2 is fairly easy, but I can’t think of any benefit to doing that… the Mesh you have after the loading the OBJ or FBX will be (at best) the same as the Mesh you get at the end. At worst, the roundtrip through GLTFExporter->GLTFLoader may introduce performance or correctness problems.